# Python Beautiful Soup Scraping Individual Pages from One Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I plan to scrape this website so that I can get the squad data for each premier league team. Can someone help with how I would do that? Under this URL, under the heading Premier League I can see a list of teams inside a bunch of UI tags.

Also I notice each team URL is like this - https://www.skysports.com/arsenal, and inside that page the link for squad looks like - https://www.skysports.com/arsenal-squad.

But this is also true of non premier league teams.

Also initially I was able to scrape the premier league table for the teams and their points etc and put that in a csv..So maybe could I use that to then construct the URLs to get the individual team data. ? Below is what I had in my csv for example

Position, Team, Pl, W, D, L, F, A, GD, Pts
1,Manchester City,9,7,2,0,26,3,23,23
2,Liverpool,9,7,2,0,16,3,13,23

Comment: Use the links on the master pages to resolve the correct address of the detail pages, instead of guessing the URL.

Comment: Right, I suppose I am having trouble visualizing the architecture of how I would go about this from the outset. My question is really around from a high level what would i need to do

Answer (score 1):

Use the links on the master pages to resolve the correct address of the detail pages, instead of guessing the URL( which as you mention fails for the premiere league).

You need use beautifulsoup thusly:

1. Obtain the link (`a`) that links to detail page you need.
2. Obtain the href of this link
3. If the link is relative, you need to resolve it against the current page, so extract the path from the url using urllib, then use `newpath=os.abspath(os.path.join(curpath,href))` , stick this back into the url of your domain.
4. Now you have the detail page's name.

You might come up with a few different cases for what kind of page you're on, look for an id or class that only occurs on the page you're looking at, or a string pattern to determine which page parser to use.

Comment: Thanks. I have all the urls now in a list. With beautiful soup would I be able to go to each url from one main program and then pull the team info? I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that